# Pivot auto date filter in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, pivot-table

I have issue while filter today date in VBA. Because the format changed for each user. How to set it as universal format?

My code:

```
'FILTER TODAY DATE IN PIVOT
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandIer
  
  Dim DateToday As Date
  DateToday = Format(Date, "M/DD/YYYY")
  
  With Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CCN_Created_Date")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = DateToday
  End With
  
  With Me.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    .CIearAIIFiIters
    .CurrentPage = DateToday
  End With
  
  Exit Sub
  
ErrorHandler:
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAII
  MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess thats the point of localisation settings. You cannot force how user' dates are displayed. Either you have to work with strings or somehow detect the local format and work with it. Or just stick you raw dates in number format and let excel handle formatting

Comment: @mobus as you said. If I set filter cell format as number it works. May I know why excel date format's is adjust for each system by local format. Even I set it as MM/DD/YYYY....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Need to Update VBA

```
DateToday= Format(Date, Number)
```

- Set pivot filter cell format as Number

If  the Pivot sheet Activated then the Date automatically filtered itself
.

@Mobus Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding a column to the PivotTables' data sources that will always reflect the current date.

Suppose CCN_Created_Date is in column A and you have one header row, you could add a column called "Current Date Filter"

```
=IF($A2=TODAY(),"Current date","")
```

Then add that as a filter to your PivotTable, and select the value "Current Date". That way, whenever you refresh the PivotTable, it will always filter the data to the current date. You won't need to write any VBA.

Comment: I already think this method. But I don't need extra column.

Comment: The source file is ms access, also it has nearly 45 columns.. I made the pivot by connection. So that I need some alternative....